# Is there a plugin equivalent to Governance plugin for SonarQube 5.6.3?

Tags: sonarqube

I am running SonarQube 5.6.3, I am able to get the output UI.

I want the report to be generated as a pdf. Is there any free plugin with features like what the Governance plugin offers?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, no open-source plugin offers this feature.

Comment: but until 5.5 report plug in offers this,is this not feasible 5.6 ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a free utility that creates a PDF from a web page.
Check out wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf. We use this for all Sonar dashboard reports.